# Does the loading animation code go on the page with the form or the page for processing?

Tags: forms

I've looked on SO and other places but could not find a definitive answer.

Most answers seemed to be for single page forms and processing.

If I have a form on page1.html that posts to page page2.html, which page should contain the code to display a loading animation?

Comment: I'd put the animation on page 1 - display it while waiting for a successful form submission, then redirect the user to page 2 when the submission is confirmed.

Comment: Like @skwidbreth said. Most "Loading animations" are just gifs that your hide and show at the appropriate time.